# Is this a valid JSONObject & if yes then how do I iterate to get all the values

Tags: parse-platform, json

I have this response from server which is a valid JSON.

```
{"Avg":[{"avg":3,"rcid":"ww44sd"},{"avg":4,"rcid":"ww24hj"},{"avg":3,"rcid":"ww36hd"},{"avg":4,"rcid":"ww89yx"},{"avg":3,"rcid":"ww64tf"},{"avg":4,"rcid":"ww76py"}]}
```

I wrote the following code but I fail to understand how this is not a JSONObject. Logcat shows this error
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject`

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("avgfunc", params, new FunctionCallback<JSONObject>() {
public void done(JSONObject response, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) { 

try {
      JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);
      JSONArray jsonarr = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("Avg");
           for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject json = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
               //do some processing...
               }
      } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
      }
```

In my CloudCode I am generating the response like this

```
Parse.Cloud.define("avgfunc", function(request, response) {
  var idlist = request.params.someids;
  var _ = require("underscore");

  var newlist = {"Avg":[]}; //This is to initialize & later push

   ......
  _.each(idlist,function(categoryid){
   ......
  query.find({
  success: function(results) {
   if(results.length==0){
    console.log("No row found");
    }
    //some more processing of data & then finally push

    newlist.Avg.push({              //& this
       "avg":somevalue,
       "rcid":somevalue
     });
    }
    if(counter == idlist.length)
    {
      response.success(newlist); //this sends the response as shown above
    } 
  },
  error: function() {
    response.error("error.");
  }
 });
});
```

});

So I wanna know how to construct proper JSONObject so I can iterate over individual items later in android.

Edit : Stack Trace

```
 2937-2937/com.muffin.testapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
        at com.muffin.testapp.CollinfoActivity$2.done(CollinfoActivity.java:133)
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 133 is `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getAVGrating", params, new FunctionCallback<JSONObject>() {`

Comment: there must be something you're not showing us here..can you show us the full stack trace, not just the exception message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json string seem to be legit.  Here's some code to parse it.

I'm using json-simple-1.1.1.jar downloaded from here:
https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar&can=2&q=

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting example...");
        String str = "{\"Avg\":[{\"avg\":3,\"rcid\":\"ww44sd\"},{\"avg\":4,\"rcid\":\"ww24hj\"},{\"avg\":3,\"rcid\":\"ww36hd\"},{\"avg\":4,\"rcid\":\"ww89yx\"},{\"avg\":3,\"rcid\":\"ww64tf\"},{\"avg\":4,\"rcid\":\"ww76py\"}]}";
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(str);
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) obj;
        Object avgObj = json.get("Avg");
        JSONArray avgArray = (JSONArray) avgObj;
        System.out.println("JSON Strings for averages:");
        for(int i=0;i<avgArray.size();i++) {
            JSONObject current = (JSONObject)avgArray.get(i);
            System.out.println("\t" + current);
        }
        System.out.println("Averages:");
        for(int i=0;i<avgArray.size();i++) {
            JSONObject current = (JSONObject)avgArray.get(i);
            System.out.println("\tAvergage: " + current.get("avg"));
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Here's the output.

```
Starting example...
JSON Strings for averages:
    {"avg":3,"rcid":"ww44sd"}
    {"avg":4,"rcid":"ww24hj"}
    {"avg":3,"rcid":"ww36hd"}
    {"avg":4,"rcid":"ww89yx"}
    {"avg":3,"rcid":"ww64tf"}
    {"avg":4,"rcid":"ww76py"}
Averages:
    Avergage: 3
    Avergage: 4
    Avergage: 3
    Avergage: 4
    Avergage: 3
    Avergage: 4
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue. Nothing is wrong with your JSON, it's just the `callFunctionInBackground` function that parse itself all JSONArray into List<>, and JSONObject into `Hashmap<>`. So instead of getting a JSONObject you are actually getting a `Hashmap<String, Object>`.